# Running an Azure container instance using Azure Python SDK

Tags: azure, docker, containers, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I'm using Azure's Python SDK to manage Azure Container Instances (ACI) in my application. When I use the `begin_start` method to start a container, it appears to pull the image every time, causing a delay. Is there a more efficient way to run the container in ACI, such as reusing a previously pulled image to avoid the image pull on each start?

Here's how I currently start the container:

```
container_client.container_groups.begin_start(container_group_name=container_group_name, resource_group_name=RESOURCE_GROUP)
```

I'm looking for a way to reduce the startup time by reusing existing images or optimizing the ACI container startup process. Any advice or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated.